# Comparing Between datetime field in django

Tags: python, django

I have a model named Assignment in my project

This is how the Assignment model looks like

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='assignments')
    unique_code = models.CharField(max_length=11, default=assignment_uniqe_id)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(
        All_Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='assignment_subject')
    classes = models.ManyToManyField(Classes)
    submitted_by = models.ManyToManyField(Student, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + " : " + self.title
```

And I want to check weather if the current date is greater then the deadline.
Please help me out

Comment: if datetime.now() >= deadline:

Comment: It would be easier if you gave us the context of when you want to use it. (e.g. in queries, templates, ...)